# Evented api and/or callback api in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I would like to know what is the best way to handle an evented api. My first thought is wrapping it into a callback api but I have feeling that I am blocking right here and that this is not the best approach.

Given I have a lib that returns values from a db and it is evented:

```
var connection = new Connection(config);
 var query = new Query();
 query.on('data',function(row){});
 query.on('done',function(){});
```

This is my take ...

```
 getAllCustomer(clb){

    var connection = new Connection(config);
    var query = new Query();
    var results = [];

    query.on('data',function(row){
        results.push(row);
    });
    query.on('done',function(){

        clb(results);

    });

    connection.execute(query);
    connection.close();
 }
```

I would like to use that in an hapijs or expressjs app

like to use it like this

```
 handler: function(request,reply){

    getAllCustomer(function(err,result){
        reply(result);
    });
 }
```

getAllCustomers() seems to be blocking until the query is done!
 So what would be the recommended way to handle that? 
 Is the design dessicion right to wrap the evented api in a callback api?
 Or should I pass the streaming rows along with expressjs / hapijs?
 So I am looking for a best practise way ... the node way...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code example that you provided `getAllCustomers()` will be blocking, only if `connection.execute(query)` is blocking - and it seems the case, cause otherwise if it was asynchronous - it would have been closed by a subsequent call to `connection.close()` before it even had a chance to run a query.
If it isn't sync/blocking - than you need to clode sonnection in a `done` callback

Comment: I changed the api now I to the close call in the don callback and it seems better,... thanks!